# Horizontal scrollbar only visible when vertical scrollbar is visible

Tags: css

A `div` contains a `table` with some data.

- The `table` always has to be at least the with of the container `div`
- If the `table` can't fit the width of the `div` it's allowed to exceed the width (with a horizontal scrollbar)

.

```
div.container {
  overflow: auto;
}

table.data {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

But if the `table` is heigher than the `div` but fits the width the horizontal scrollbar is still visible and the horizontal scrollable length is equal to the width of the vertical scrollbar.

How to get rid of the horizontal scrollbar when it's not needed? But of course I still want to show the horizontal scrollbar if the `table` is actually wider than the `div` (minus the width of the vertical scrollbar)

Comment: can you share the html as well, this question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

These are Three Types Of Overflow We Get When We Add `Overflow:auto;` it hides the unnecessary scrollbar by itself.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.table {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.container2 {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.table2 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.container3 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 320px;
  overflow: auto;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.table3 {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        I Am OverFlowing Both Horizontally & Vertically.
      </td>
      <td>
        My Size Is 200px/200px.
      </td>
      <td>
        Container Size Is 300px/300px.
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <table class="table2" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        I Am OverFlowing Only Vertically .
      </td>
      <td>
        My Size Is 600px/300px.
      </td>
      <td>
        Container Size Is 700px/200px.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="container3">
  <table class="table3" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        I Am OverFlowing Only Horizontally .
      </td>
      <td>
        My Size Is 600px/300px.
      </td>
      <td>
        Container Size Is 500px/320px.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```